# How to listen global mouse and keyboard events on linux platform using Qt?

Tags: qt, mouseevent, keyboard-events

I use Qt to develop my application, and I want to listen the global mouse and keyboard events, so I can do something after detect these events. On windows platform, I use SetWindowsHookEx API. But I don't know how to do the similar thing on Linux.

My code on Windows as below:

```
/*********************listen mouse event*****************************/
mouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, mouseProc, NULL, 0);
if (mouseHook == NULL) {
qDebug() << "Mouse Hook Failed";
}
/*********************listen keyboard event*****************************/
keyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, keyBoardProc, NULL, 0);
if (keyboardHook == NULL) {
qDebug() << "Keyboard Hook Failed";
}
```

Thank you for your answer sincerely!

Answer (score 2):

Use the vast and helpful [Qt Event System](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html). That way you can use the same code on Windows as well as Linux.

I would recommend adding a `eventFilter` to your application. If the event caught is a `QEvent::KeyPress` or `QEvent::MouseButtonPress`( or `QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick` based on your requirement), take the necessary action.

If the event filter is to be applied for a particular widget in the main window, in the constructor of the main window, add

```
ui->myWidget->installEventFilter(this);
```

Now you need to implement the protected method `eventFilter` for the main window.

In the header file.

```
protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent* event);
```

Implementation

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent* event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        QKeyEvent* keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event);
        qDebug() << "Ate key press " << keyEvent->text();
        return true;
    }
    else if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
    {
        qDebug() << "Mouse press detected";
        return true;
    }
    // standard event processing
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

It is also possible to filter all events for the entire application, by installing an event filter on the `QApplication` or `QCoreApplication` object. You can read more on that from the documentation link I provided in the first line.

If the event filter has to be reused, I would recommend adding a dummy class which inherits from `QObject`. In this class you can just implement the function `eventFilter`. You can now pass an instance of this class to the function `installEventFilter` and communicate with the other objects using SIGNALS.

EDIT:

If you are looking to capture events even outside the application, Qt itself does not support that (yet). But you can use the Qxt library that adds support for it using the [QxtGlobalShortcut](http://libqxt.bitbucket.org/doc/tip/qxtglobalshortcut.html) class.

Comment: I believe he wants to listen to the events outside of his application.

Comment: @thuga: Looking at the question, I was under the impression that he wanted to act on events only within the application. Let me edit my answer to include system wide events. :)